# Phonegap 2.1.0 and android 4.1: Text input issue

Tags: android, cordova, input, textinput, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I developed an app using phonegap 2.1.0, everything works perfectly fine in Iphone and Android 2.3.x and 4.0.x. However when I run my app in Android **4.1.2** (Jelly Bean, Galaxy Nexus), text inputs stop working after a few strokes.

I have searched on the web (dozens of results) and it seems to be a common problem, no solution has been provided for this... NONE!

Phonegap team says that this bug is fixed since phonegap 2.0.0, but clearly this is not true.

I know there is a similar question in SO, tried that already and didn`t work. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just finished dealing with this problem in work myself. Phonegap-2.1 seems to fix the issue at least for the app I'm responsible for. Other recommendations are to check if you're using a framework which may have * { webkit-user-select: none; }

Comment: I've already tried phonegap 2.1 and the problem persists. Also I'm using jquery mobile, think it has something to do with my problem? @sciritai

Comment: @sciritai Holy crap how long I was debugging this input issue, then I stumbled across your comment with the `* { webkit-user-select: none; }`.  Cheers!